# Style.Transform for phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

i start programming for mobile with phone gap.
i use this line to scale my iframe in browser,
    document.getElementById("IFM").style.transform="scale(0.5,0.5)";

it works in my pc browser, but it doesn't work in my android application!

Answer (score 2):

use `webkitTransform` in addition to `transform`

```
document.getElementById("IFM").style.webkitTransform = "scale(0.5)";
```

Comment: Android browser uses webkit, `transform` is supported at least as far back as Android 2.1 (http://caniuse.com/#search=transform).  Is the `IFM` element [transformable](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-2d-transforms/#TermTransformableElement)?  Try setting `.style.display = 'block'`

Comment: Ifm is iframe, and scalable in browsers, can i put scale function in onResize() of <body> ?

Comment: I've tested on Android 4.2 and iOS 6, this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vvDV/4/show) scales properly in Android, iOS height is off but it does scale.  Which version Android are you testing?

Comment: I tested on 2.1. If i build on 4.1, anyone who has lower than 4.1 cannot run this application?

Comment: excuse me, i think you can help me in this question too, would you please see this link? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694387/i-cant-set-anything-with-config-xml